# How to add defer or async attribute to wp_add_inline_script?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, deferred

First I enqueue a script using:

```
wp_enqueue_script( "script", plugins_url( "/test/js/script.js", PATH ), array("jquery"), VERSION, true );
```

Then I'm inserting an inline script after "script".

```
wp_add_inline_script( "script", "console.log('hello world');" );
```

Now I need to add **defer or async attribute** to my inline script, is there a way to do this to a script embedded by **wp_add_inline_script()** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wp_enqueue_script( "script", plugins_url( "/test/js/script.js", PATH ), array("jquery"), VERSION, true );`

`wp_script_add_data( 'script', 'async/defer' , true );`

[see more](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_script_add_data/)

Comment: Hi, Look at this. WordPress twentytwenty theme is using the same function to enable async https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/bcb8ee6dcf8ea69bc5e60ff196d9452d5b14eaa1/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/functions.php#L212\

Comment: Is not working for me for  `wp_enqueue_script(...$src);` `wp_script_add_data('rollbar' , 'async/defer', 'true');`

Comment: Please take a look at TwentyTwenty theme here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/bcb8ee6dcf8ea69bc5e60ff196d9452d5b14eaa1/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/functions.php#L212

Comment: @StevenAguilar it is either defer OR async, not both.

Comment: In order for this to work the custom script loader class from the twentytwenty theme is required.  `wp_script_add_data` does not have this option by default.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't what you're looking for, but `defer` doesn't work unless there's a `src` attribute. I.e. it doesn't work on inline scripts.

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> `defer`
> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded.
> Scripts with the defer attribute will prevent the DOMContentLoaded event from firing until the script has loaded and finished evaluating.
> **Warning: This attribute must not be used if the src attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts)**, in this case it would have no effect.
> The defer attribute has no effect on module scripts — they defer by default.
> Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in the order in which they appear in the document.
> This attribute allows the elimination of parser-blocking JavaScript where the browser would have to load and evaluate scripts before continuing to parse. async has a similar effect in this case.