# wp_script_add_data not working for async defer

Tags: php, wordpress, asynchronous, deferred

I'm currently working on trying to get `async` and `defer` to work with `wp_script_add_data`. I came across the following article to achieve this task.
[How to add defer or async attribute to wp_add_inline_script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282112/how-to-add-defer-or-async-attribute-to-wp-add-inline-script)
However, when I pass the `wp_script_add_data` it doesn't add anything to the script.

[image]

Here is what the code looks like:

```
   // Register/Enqueue the script source if it is configured
    if (array_key_exists('path', $s)) {
      // Replace constant tags with real constants
      $s['path'] = self::localize($s['path'], $s['localize']);
      $src = self::scriptArgs($s['handle'], $s['path'], $s['in_footer']);

      wp_register_script(...$src);
      wp_enqueue_script(...$src);

      // // If set add async to script
      if ($s['async'] === true) {
        $t = $s['handle'];
        $t .= '-inline';
        // var_dump($src);
        wp_script_add_data('rollbar' , 'async/defer', true );
      }

      // Add inline script to source script if it exists
       if (array_key_exists('inline', $s)) {
         $s['inline']['contents'] = self::getFileContents($s['inline']['path'], $s['localize']);
         wp_add_inline_script($s['handle'], $s['inline']['contents'], $s['inline']['position']);
       }
    }
```

I'm passing `async/defer` to `wp_script_add_data` adter `wp_enque_script`, however the script is not adding `async defer`.How can I go about making this work?

when I add 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' it works:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make **wp_script_add_data** work with **defer**, I defined the custom filter like the following. This is working well. :)

```js
add_filter('script_loader_tag', function ($tag, $handle){
  foreach (['async', 'defer'] as $attr) {
    if (!wp_scripts()->get_data($handle, $attr)) {
      continue;
    }
    // Prevent adding attribute when already added in #12009.
    if (!preg_match(":\s$attr(=|>|\s):", $tag)) {
        $tag = preg_replace(':(?=></script>):', " $attr", $tag, 1);
    }
    // Only allow async or defer, not both.
    break;
  }
  return $tag;
}, 10, 2);

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'rare-candy-assets',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/assets/main.js',
    [],
    filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/dist/assets/main.js'),
    true
  );
  wp_script_add_data('rare-candy-assets', 'defer', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the answer you were hoping for, but `async` or `defer` only works if there's a `src` attribute present. I.e. it doesn't work on inline scripts.

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> `defer`
> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded.
> Scripts with the defer attribute will prevent the DOMContentLoaded event from firing until the script has loaded and finished evaluating.
> **Warning: This attribute must not be used if the src attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts)**, in this case it would have no effect.
> The defer attribute has no effect on module scripts — they defer by default.
> Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in the order in which they appear in the document.
> This attribute allows the elimination of parser-blocking JavaScript where the browser would have to load and evaluate scripts before continuing to parse. async has a similar effect in this case.